# Integrating JS scrollbar with CSS overflow property inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, widget, styles

I'm trying to use a Facebook-ticker style scrollbar for my Recent Tweets widget. [This is the website.](http://thinkrasta.com/home)

I have found the required script. It's called [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll). However, even after downloading the example file, I'm unable to integrate this into the site. 
Code, for reference:

tweets-widget.php: pastebin.com/bqefjDV4

jtwt.js: pastebin.com/ukkSWkhM

It says that I have to load jQuery 1.6.8 and jQuery UI, but loading one of these files causes a problem with my jQuery based featured image on the homepage. Can you tell me how I can load these files inside the Recent Tweets div without causing a conflict?

Thank you for any help and suggestions!

P.S. I know, I can use the CSS overflow:auto; property to add a normal scrollbar, but I need the facebook-ticker style scrollbar.

Comment: Could you provide a working exemple or a fiddle ? You would guess that your problem is related with AJAX loading. You could also try http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ , which is very sturdy.

Comment: Sure, [here](http://thinkrasta.com/slimscroll/index.htm)

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi he means your code mate. not just the plugin. also please add them to your question by editing , not at the comment

Comment: I have already linked all relevant code in the question, it's on Pastebin.

Comment: It's quite hard to help you with a pastebin. I meant a fiddle or a real page demonstrating the problem. However, the Jscrollpane plugin I linked is compatible with older Jquerys, you should try it.

Comment: Jscrollpane isn't working with 1.7.1 or 1.6.4 either :/ Can you please help me with jscrollpane?

Answer (score 0):

So the crux of your problem is, slimScroll is incompatible with the version of jquery that your site runs.

Try backporting slimScroll.js to work with your site's version of jQuery.  Or forward-porting your site to work with the latest jquery.

Comment: oh. Okay. Thanks a lot. I think I'll just use the JScrollPane suggested by mdi, then.

Comment: sorry, but I was loading jQuery 1.6.4.min.js on my website, same as specified on the slimScroll integration page. Which version incompatibility are you mentioning here?